# Protect against script injection using markdown

Tags: c#, javascript, html, markdown, javascript-injection

I want to protect my page when a user inputs the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("hi");
</script>
```

I'm using ShowDown:

```
jQuery.fn.markDown = function() 
{
    return this.each(function() {
        var caller = this;
        var converter = new Showdown.converter();

        var text = $(caller).text();
        var html = converter.makeHtml(text);

        $(caller).html(html);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution that could be effective would be to strip all the tag in the source or HTML encode the tag before it is transformed with Showdown.

For how to strip all the HTML tag, there are a couple of way to do it that you can find in this question :

[Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

For how to HTML encode the tag, you can use this :

```
myString.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
```

Note: This will remove you the ability to use HTML in Showdown.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sanitize html on a .NET server-side code, I'd advise you use [Microsoft web protection library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/), after transforming the markup to html, before rendering it to the page.
e.g. the following snippet:

```
x = @"<div>safe</div>
       <script type='text/javascript'>
         alert('hi');
       </script>";
return Microsoft.Security.Application.Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(x);
```

returns `<div>safe</div>`

http://wpl.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

The ShowDown page strips any javascript, so I don't know what you mean exactly. But you can't do this on the client. If this is never going to be submitted to the server, then it doesn't matter. However, 99% of the time, you want to store it on the server.

I think the best approach is to create a server side DOM object out of the html that is submitted (which could be spoofed and bypass ShowDown) and look for any script or other dangerous tags. This is not so simple!

The best compromise for me is to use a server side markdown language (like https://github.com/charliesome/bbsharp) that you could then use to generate the html. You would then html encode any html before passing it to the tool that converts the markdown to HTML.

Comment: No, it does not strip Javascript.  Put in a tag with a `mouseover` attribute and watch it run.  It won't strip `<script>` tags either; it just doesn't execute them in the preview.

Comment: That's why you removed your answer? In any case, my answer is about the fact that it needs to be done server side. The client side would be only for creating a preview for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) which works very well for filtering user input and is highly customizable.

I assume you can use it with MarkDown, although I never tried.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using MVC (C#). PHP is not an option for me. Thanks anyway. If you don't mind, please, delete the answer, I want other people seeing this question without answer.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to ask people to remove their answers

Comment: @Daniel Peñalba: the answer can be of use to some other people that use PHP. To avoid confusion in the future please be sure to correctly tag your questions (there was no C# tag...). Don't worry, the mass of users of SO ensures you will get other answers very soon (and you already have).